# a simple date in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

please check my code, I've created a simple date in JS but it's not working, I'm following a tutorial and I have the exact code.

```html
<html>
    <head>
 <title>Clock</title>
 <script>
     function time() {
  var time = new Date();
  var hours = time.getHours();
  var mins = time.getMinutes();
  var secs = time.getSeconds();

  if (secs<10) {
   secs = "0" + secs;
  }
  if (mins<10) {
   secs = "0" + mins;
  }

  document.getElementById("thetime").innerHTML=hours+":"+mins+":"+secs;

  var timer = setTimeout(function(){time()},500);
     }
 </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="time()">
     <div id="thetime"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Define "not working". Also, you can just do `setTimeout(time, 500)`

Comment: I've turned your code into a StackOverflow Code Snippet and it appears to work as it should. What's the problem?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly -- `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function ` is thrown.

Comment: James, setTimeOut is not called, so @unknownDude doesn't see the time passing every 500 milliseconds.

Comment: Ah, more reason to support a StackOverflow Code Snippet JavaScript Console! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `function time() {...}` and `var time = new Date();`. The local variable shadows the function, meaning that inside `setTimeout(function(){time()},500);`, `time` refers to the `Date` object, not the function.

**Solution:** Rename either of them.

Answer (score 1):

Also,

replace this part of the code:

```
if (mins<10) {
            secs = "0" + mins;
        }
```

with this:

```
if (mins<10) {
            mins= "0" + mins;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `setInterval()` instead of timeout

```
    function time() {
      //Your stuff here...
    }
    var timer = setInterval(function(){time()},500);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k8ucauaa/)

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using the same variable name as function name. It tried to call the variable as a function. Naming it `currentTime` makes it work.

```
function time() {
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var hours = currentTime.getHours();
    var mins = currentTime.getMinutes();
    var secs = currentTime.getSeconds();

    if (secs<10) {
        secs = "0" + secs;
    }
    if (mins<10) {
        secs = "0" + mins;
    }
    document.getElementById("thetime").innerHTML=hours+":"+mins+":"+secs;

    var timer = setTimeout(function(){time()},500);
}
```

Comment: Personally, I think `var timer` is not in the right place.

Comment: why? I think so too, it should be outside the function but in the tutorial its inside and it words. Idk i'Mjust learning JS.

Comment: It serves no purpose as it goes out of scope immediately, but it isn't "incorrect" in that it violates no conventions. If there were a possibility of multiple timers, then using `var timer` could be used to clear timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

You are naming a var `var time` the same your function `time()`. You should rename one of them.

For example name your function `customTimer`. You call this function from the `setTimeout` and from your `onload` in the html

```html
<html>
<head>
   <title>Clock</title>
   <script>
  function customTimer() {
     var time = new Date();
     var hours = time.getHours();
     var mins = time.getMinutes();
     var secs = time.getSeconds();

     if (secs < 10) {
        secs = "0" + secs;
     }
     if (mins < 10) {
        mins = "0" + mins;
     }

     document.getElementById("thetime").innerHTML = hours + ":" + mins + ":" + secs;

     var timer = setTimeout(function () { customTimer() }, 500);
  }
   </script>
</head>
<body onload="customTimer()">
   <div id="thetime"></div>
</body>
</html>
```